# Guardar valores en pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cómo podría guardar los valores de `displayMousePosition()`, algo así como

```
x, y, rgb = pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pyautogui.displayMousePosition()`  **monitoriza** la posición **constantemente** del puntero del ratón e **imprime** la posición y valor RGB del pixel, por tanto no es un método indicado si quieres capturar los valores.

En su lugar puedes combinar `pyautogui.position()` para obtener las coordenadas y `pyautogui.pixel()` para los valores RGB de ese pixel:

```
import pyautogui

while True: 
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    rgb = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
    # Haz lo que quieras con los valores x, y e rgb
    print("x: {}, y: {}, RGB: {}".format(x, y, rgb))
```

Comment: Gracias brother, me estaba matando la cabeza para guardarlo por separado.